# Dynamically change the format of DevExpress report at runtime?

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

Is it possible to have one report with the same or similar data and change the format of the report at run-time, for example, one report has the customer name at the top left, while the other has it at the top right or something like one report shows the customers last 10 orders, while another shows the last 5 and the heading for each order is different.

Comment: Create multiple reports and then load them at runtime, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create & add - or move - controls in the report's constructor or before_print event(s). Indeed, what you're actually doing in the designer is modifying the report's InitializeComponent() function which then gets called at runtime from the constructor.

As mentioned by previous posters, a great way to see how to do this would be to browse through the .designer file.

Answer (score 0):

for different special formats you can make it in design time and get it's code from .designer file and cut and paste it into a new function.

for special height you can get height of each object after assign text and then calculate the location of next object.

```
xrRichText1.LocationFloat = new DevExpress.Utils.PointFloat(25F, hed + 10F);
```